# Get taxonomy slug from url

Tags: urls, slug

Sorry I'm new to taxonomies & trying to learn quickly.

I've set up sectors and assigned a post to it. If I go to the post, I can see the URL has
www.mydomain.com/sectors/auto/

How can I get auto from the URL?
Thanks

Comment: Hi... try printing the query_vars using the filter 'query_vars', and look for the key with the value.

Answer (score 13):

I think you are looking for [`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

```
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$sector = get_queried_object()->name;
```