# Custom taxonomy query for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I have a custom post type called `news` with a custom taxonomy called `news category`. Right now I have a template called `taxonomy-news_category-press.php` where *press* is one of the `news_categories`. The query I'm using is:

```
$query_args = array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'news_category',
    'term'      => 'press',
    'post_type' => 'news',
)
```

I don't like this though. It's hard coded and if I change press to something else it will break. I want to replace `press` in `'term' => 'press'` with a variable that will pull in the `news_category` from the URL so it will be responsive with any `news_category`. I understand that I'll need to change the template file to `taxonomy-news_category.php` when I solve this variable issue.

Comment: You can use default category set of wordpress in custom post types like this `'taxonomies' => array('category'),` when you register a post type and use the default functionality, more information can be found here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to an answer posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26357/94192). The code is

```
$term_slug  = get_query_var( 'term' );
$query_args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'news_category',
    'term'      => $term_slug,
    'post_type' => 'news'
 );
```